# Datetime comparison

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, datagridview, compare

My program is reading data from SQL Server like this:

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(4))
{
    message.WazneDo = reader.GetDateTime(4);
}
```

This code read datetime from SQL Server. Then I will load it to datagridview:

```
WypozyczZwrocDb _dost1 = new WypozyczZwrocDb();
Global.listWypozyczZwroc = _dost1.PokazZar();
Global.fMain.Tabela.DataSource = Global.listWypozyczZwroc;
```

How to compare with today's date? I want change the row color.

I tried:

```
DateTime dzis = DateTime.Now;

if(Tabela.Rows[Tabela.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value > dzis)

if(Tabela.Rows[Tabela.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value > dzis.ToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Compare()` will allow you to use comparative operators in a conditional statement based on the `int` returned.

[DateTime.Compare() msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx)